# How to have Apache output really ALL errors?

Tags: php, apache

So I set display_errors to "On" 
and error_reporting to E_ALL|E_STRICT 
and even display_startup_errors shall be "On".

Yet, Apache will give me a blank page if I forget a $ or a ).

On CLI though I get a message.

How have that message displayed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your comment discussion hints, the problem is that you're trying to set it in your script.

In order to run a script, the PHP interpreter must first parse that script.  If the parsing fails (ie: there is a syntax error), the script is invalid, and the interpreter doesn't run it at all -- it emits a fatal error.

So, a syntax error is a *compile-time* error, not a *run-time* error.

So, if you forget a $, ), or ;, for example, your script has invalid syntax.  Therefore the script is not run.  Therefore your ini_set() and similar statements are never run.

The interpreter simply doesn't get that far.

The only way to get those errors to output is to set those variable *before* the interpreter tries to parse your broken script, ie: in php.ini (or perhaps in .htaccess if you're running under mod_php).  That way, the error reporting configuration is set before the interpreter attempts to parse your broken script.

---

When PHP runs your script, it goes through basically three steps (this is simplified):

1) Parse the script -- it scans through the whole script top to bottom, and creates a representation of it.  If you made a syntax error, it fails to parse, and emits a fatal error, and stops.

2) Compiles the script -- it takes the output of step one, and turns it into machine code.

3) Runs the script -- it runs that machine code, which is your script, starting essentially at line 1.

The problem you're having is that during step 1 (parsing), PHP has not yet run ANY of your code (it doesn't, until step 3).  So the settings it's running under are the default ones from PHP ini -- what you'd see if you wrote a one-line script with only a single phpinfo() call in it.

Answer (score 1):

1. This belongs to serverFault
2. are you sure you restarted apache?
3. are you sure you edited correct php.ini file?
4. try error_reporting set to E_ALL

These suggestions/points should be done if you're editing server configuration, because you can't handle parse error in php script!

Comment: 1. sorry, I thought you are setting it in php.ini 2. look to first pint 3. look to first point 4. you told it's E_ALL|E_STRICT - are you sure your provider does allow ini_set(); ?

Comment: I am my own provider, so to say. ini_set and the settings alls show an effect, though not my desired one - there's my question aiming at. The pipe | indicates a bitwise OR and makes PHP report E_ALL and E_STRICT (which isn't covered by E_ALL, surprise, surprise)

Comment: and why donť you try to set it in php.ini instead of in php script ?